# Is it possible to upload a file on a secondary page?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, cookies

I have a form with a file input which accepts large files. The intention is to upload this file to a remote server.

```
<input type="file" id="userfile"></input>
```

When a user chooses a [potentially large] file, I want to redirect to a secondary page (on the same domain) which shows the upload progress along with other information.

I can use the native File API to grab the Blob and read the file with FileReader, but only on the page with the form (the first page). I want to delay this reading/uploading process until the second page.

Is there a way to POST the file reference somehow to the second page, and then upload the file from there? Or is this impossible by design for security reasons? Or, some way to store the file reference in a cookie or local storage to be read by the second page?

I could double POST - first to the secondary page, and then POST/PUT to the appropriate final destination. However, I want to avoid this redundancy, which would cause further delays for the user.

Comment: Why can't you show "the upload progress along with other information" on the first page?

Comment: both pages are open in the same tab?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to POST the file reference somehow to the second page, and then upload the file from there?

No.

---

To get this sort of effect, the usual way is to remove the second page from the process entirely and use Ajax for any communication you need to do with the server before uploading the file to the correct place.